# Setting child class attributes through constructors: Bad practice?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm using a base class to declare the main attributes and functions to manipulate those attributes of a family of classes I'll define later. I've found that redefining class variables in child classes doesn't actually have any effect and have been define `set_attribute()` type members to set values as seen below.

### Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    void set_val(const char& c) { val = c; }
    void print_val() { std::cout << "Val = " << val << std::endl; }
protected:
    char val = 'a';
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    char val = 'c'; // No effect
    char derived_val = 'b';
public:
    // Constructor assigns derived_val to val
    Derived() { set_val(derived_val); }; 
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Base base;
    base.print_val(); // 'a'
    Derived derived;
    derived.print_val(); // 'b'
}
```

#### Output:

```
Val = a
Val = b
```

Now this works but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, or even if it's a good practice to use class inheritance this way. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Since it's `protected`, you could just write `val = derived_val;` in `Derived::Derived()`.

Comment: How is that a field is non-static and initializable from the class definition, am i missing something here ? default values in c11 or c14 ?

Comment: @MiroRodozov C++11 and a loosening of the rules a bit further in C++14. Decent write-up here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization

Comment: @user4581301 10x man now it's clear. I am ancient, not the syntax wrong ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't exactly say that it is bad practice, just completely unnecessary.

The reason why

```
char val = 'c';
```

has no effect because you are defining a new `val` in `Derived`, which hides the `val` in `Base`. When you call `print_val`, it only sees `Base::val`, not `Derived::val`. And so it prints `Base::val`.

You can change `Base::val` directly in the constructor of `Derived`, instead of redefining it:

```
Derived() { val = 'c'; }
```

Comment: I had no idea this was possible. Thanks!